# spring.config.additional-location does not work for absolute / relative parent directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

`java -jar my.jar --spring.config.additional-location='file:../some-config.yml`

- `some-config.yml` is not loaded from the parent directory (or an absolute path e.g. `/path/to/some-config.yml`)

  - if I move `some-config.yml` to the working directory, it is still not loaded correctly.
  - if I move `some-config.yml` to the working directory, and rename it to `application.yml`, Spring will load it -- but this is the default behavior and not what I need.

---

How do I get Spring to load my config file from the exact path I specify.

---

**Temporary Workaround**

I've created a symbolic link in the working directory which points to `../application-xyz.yml` and set `spring.profiles.include: xyz` in the in-build `application.yml`. This will suffice for now, and in general cleans things up, but it is strange that I cannot point to a specific file via `spring.config.additional-location`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use spring.config.additional-location to specify the config locations (i.e., folder, directory). Providing it a specific file is not the supported behaviour.

Check the documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Also, if you want to use a non-standard file name, you'll have to use the spring.config.name property.